# EBCDIC data load into oracle

Tags: oracle, load, ebcdic, comp-3

I need to load this into a table in oracle. Need the table datatype definition in oracle and SQL*Loader code. the upto 500 times is ok, if I get to read the data in the file to be loaded, then I can apply other oracle concepts like Unpivot to transpose from columns to rows. At least, if you can give create table script for data type definition and sql*loader for the sample data. That will be a good starting point.
Cobol CopyBook with

```
00071   01  P-DATA.                                  
00072       05  FILLER           PIC X(11).                
00073       05  F-COUNT          PIC S9(04)  BINARY.       
00074       05  F-DATA          OCCURS 1 TO 500 TIMES     
00075                            DEPENDING ON F-COUNT.
00077           10  D-EFF-DT     PIC S9(9)   COMP-3.       
00078           10  D-FEE        PIC S9V99   COMP-3.       
00079       05  F-A-DATA               OCCURS 2 TIMES.           
00080           10  A-EFF-DT     PIC S9(9)   COMP-3.       
00081           10  A-AMT        PIC S9V99   COMP-3.       
00082       05  FILLER           PIC X(692).
```

Data Sample

```
00000000h: 07 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
```

Comment: The copybook does not describe the data, is it a print of the data  ???. The copybook is mostly binary fields; the data is character

Comment: Martin- The cobol format is mentioned above, and also sample data is given.

Comment: @BruceMartin - The copybook does not describe the data, is it a print of the data ???. The copybook is mostly binary fields; the data is character